# Regex to capture word with at least one number in it

Tags: python, regex, digits

I'm almost done with all my regex stuff but i encounter another problem, i have this regex :

```
(?=.*\d)[A-Z0-9]{5,}
```

It captures all stuff i need as :

```
AP51711
```

And it works but sometimes it has a strange behaviour, as far as i understood regex (i'm noob :p ) my regex is supposed to capture things that contains at least one DIGIT !

But on this string :

```
3M BUFFING MACHINE P64392
```

The output will be :

```
['BUFFING', 'MACHINE', 'P64392']
```

I don't understand why 'BUFFING' and 'MACHINE' are captured :O

If someone could help me understand this, thanks !

Comment: Do you know what `?=` does?

Comment: @Tomerikoo It's a lookahead , no ?

Comment: The first part of your regex is a lookahead assertion which looks for anything ending with a digit. Then the rest of your regex catches everything that is of size 5 or more that contains either letters from A to Z and/or numbers from 0-9 if the lookeahead had a match

Comment: @Plopp so how can i have something that captures a part on the string if it contains one DIGIT at least ?

Comment: i'll do that: (?=[A-Z]*\d)[A-Z0-9]{5,}

Comment: Do you really need the lookahead part ? Because it can be simplified by a lot with something like `((?:\w*\d+\w*){5,})`

Comment: @Plopp That pattern requires at least 5 digits to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do that:

```
 (?=[A-Z]*\d)[A-Z0-9]{5,}
```

you have the result waited...

Answer (score 2):

You do not really need a regex here

```
sentence = "3M BUFFING MACHINE P64392"

words_with_digits = [word 
                     for word in sentence.split()
                     if any(char.isdigit() for char in word)]
print(words_with_digits)
```

This will yield

```
['3M', 'P64392']
```

Comment: Well the whole script is much more complicated....I need to handle internal reference of 9000+ products in an Odoo DB and i need two regex to handle what i must delete and keep in the product name.... ^^'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<=^|)(?=[^ ]*\d)[^ ]+
```

Code:

```
pattern = r'(?<=^|)(?=[^ ]*\d)[^ ]+' 
text = "3M BUFFING MACHINE P64392"
result = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(result)
```

Comment: Won't work, get the following error on https://pythex.org/ : Invalid regular expression: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: Please do not use the comments section to post code & updates - edit & update your post instead

Comment: everything works, there is was extra space

Answer (score 0):

You get a match for `BUFFING` and `MACHINE` because the pattern `(?=.*\d)[A-Z0-9]{5,}` asserts that from the current position there should be a digit somewhere to the right of the line.

If that assertion is true, match 5 or more times any character of the ranges A-Z and 0-9.

What you might also do is start with a word boundary to prevent a partial word match so that the lookahead does not fire on every position when scanning for a match.

Then assert 5 chars out of the accepted characters, and if that assertion is true, match at least a single digit.

Without mixing `\d` and `[0-9]`:

```
\b(?=[A-Z\d]{5})[A-Z]*\d[A-Z\d]*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/05ILUC/1).